# Printing to Python window of ArcMap using different font colors?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-window

Can i highlight the print raster in different color? Below  I have attached the shapshot, where i trying to highlight in different color only print raster, I have underlined where i trying to put different color, I am running program on Arc GIS python window.

[image]

Code i am running : Instead of getting all result by print white color, i just want to print raster name in different color while its printing the name of raster along with statistics valu , so its easy to find out each raster

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\2008\JANUARY"
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()

for raster in rasterList:
     rasterObj = arcpy.Raster(raster)
     print raster

     bands = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(raster, "MEAN")
     print "MEAN VALUE: %s" %bands
```

My desire output, i have attached below. i highlight manually by yellow color, i just want to put some code to define the color of list of raster

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work in the Python Window, but does work in the script tool dialog that displays while a tool is running:

```
arcpy.AddMessage("This is a message")
```

A Message will display in default colour

```
arcpy.AddWarning("This is a warning")
```

A Warning will display in a different colour (default appears to be green)

[image]

You can also issue an Error message, which will display in red, however this will also indicate a script failure even if the script is successful

```
arcpy.AddError("This is an error")
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on how you format your string, your warning or error message might appear as a link. Try using `arcpy.AddWarning('WARNING: this is a link')` vs. `arcpy.AddWarning(' - WARNING: this is a link')`

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe that it is possible from Python code, to specify to the Python window of ArcMap which it is being run in, what color the strings being printed using `print` statements will be coloured.

In any event, I think your question distils to:

> If I run the code below to print output to ArcMap's Python window, is
>   it possible for me to specify that "test1" will be in a red font,
>   while "test2" will be in a blue font?

```
print "test1"
print "test2"
```

At Stack Overflow I found and tested without success within the Python window of ArcMap some of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python.

When I want to show "headings" in printed output like this I tend to just place asterisks either side to make them stand out e.g. to make "test1" standout from "test2":

```
print "** {0} **".format("test1")
print "test2"
```

Comment: i have added a snapshot , what acually i am trying to do with that

Comment: Is it possible to do something like `print.color`?

Comment: @ShouvikJha When it is so easy to test I think you should.

Comment: just i have tested that command but its not working,

Comment: Please pardon me. if i had solution then why i would approach to this community....

Comment: It can be worth testing even a guess, but when I guess I test before asking others if they think my guess will work.

Comment: Your suggestion of using asterisks is a good one.  I tend to indent following lines using `print "\ttest2"` so the un-indented headings stand out also